# How to check if a PointerProperty has a value?

Tags: scripting

I've written a script that contains a bpy.props.PointerProperty which the user can set to an Object.  I'm having trouble finding any examples on how to access the contents of this property.  How do I check that it has been assigned a value before trying to use it as a bpy.types.Object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Value is `None` if not set.**

The value of a [pointer property](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PointerProperty.html#pointerproperty-property) pointing to an ID object, *ie* one that  is not defined with a type derived from a `PropertyGroup`  is `None` if not assigned.

```
>>> bpy.types.Object.foo = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)
>>> issubclass(bpy.types.Object, bpy.types.ID)
True

>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Text']

>>> C.object.bl_rna.properties['foo'].fixed_type
<bpy_struct, Struct("Object") at 0x5b41620>

>>> C.object.foo is None
True

>>> C.object.foo = C.object
>>> C.object.foo
bpy.data.objects['Text']
```