# Custom pointer property is read only?

Tags: python, error

Pretty sure i'm doing something wrong here, seems a bit strange to have a custom property default to read only (what would be the point in creating it if you can never set it to something other than the default?)

here's a bare bones test script that can be run in a scene with a default cube:

```py
import bpy
from bpy.props import CollectionProperty, PointerProperty, StringProperty

class CUSTOM_test(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_attr: StringProperty()
    
bpy.utils.register_class(CUSTOM_test)
bpy.types.Scene.my_test = CollectionProperty(type=CUSTOM_test)
bpy.types.Object.my_pointer = PointerProperty(type=CUSTOM_test)

bpy.context.scene.my_test.add()

# AttributeError:
bpy.context.active_object.my_pointer = bpy.context.scene.my_test[0]
```

which results in the following exception:
`AttributeError: bpy_struct: attribute "my_pointer" from "Object" is read-only`

So what's the solution here? I have a custom PropertyGroup stored on the Scene that I need to be able to keep track of on individual objects.

nb: cross-posted on [ba.org](https://blenderartists.org/t/custom-pointer-property-is-read-only/1315651)

Comment: You can't assign a pointer property directly. Use `bpy.context.active_object.my_pointer.my_attr = bpy.context.scene.my_test[0].my_attr`

Comment: @Gorgious can't remember the terminology, for `bpy.types.Object.foo = PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)` you can, if defined as above you cannot. Commonly for lists define an active index, get / set  the active element via a getter setter.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/209628/15543

Comment: @batFINGER Right ! Depends on the context of the add-on. I think the answer on ba https://blenderartists.org/t/custom-pointer-property-is-read-only/1315651/4 hit the nail on the head regarding your suggestion

Comment: interesting, so it's not actually creating a pointer to the propertygroup's reference, it's just initializing it _as_ a property group. seems a bit pointless to me, since the whole point of using a pointer would be to create a linked reference to an original. Ah well, just a limitation I'll have to work around. Thanks for the clarification guys.

Comment: As mentioned in a prior comment pointers to ID types are not read only and revert to None if the object pointed to is removed. Those pointing to user defined propertygroups cannot be changed at run time.... not sure how dev's could change this to handle the question scenario of pointing to reference of nth item of a collection that can be later redefined or removed.